# Check if publish method was successful with Mosquittopp

Tags: c++, amqp, mosquitto

I'm using the Mosquittopp library for C++.

The publish() method provides a callback function on_publish(int mid). mid is the id of the message, but how do I know the message was sent successfully?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method publish, you give a pointer to an int as argument. Mosquito will fill this int with the ID of the message.

In your publish call back, a MID will be given by mosquito. If this mid is the same as the one filled by the publish method, then your message is sent sucessfully.

Of course, you also must check the return value of mosquito_publish, it must be 0 (MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS). If it's not MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS, there is a problem in publishing.

You can see more detail in the source code of mosquito [here](https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/src/002887e6c4f17fa5d018c9a6fd4d6e17ff88a04f/client/pub_client.c?at=default).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The return value of publish is always zero in my case, even if connection is available (initially) and turn it down before publish is invoked. Is that the expected behavior?